# dafny initial assert in loop not verifying yet same final assert verifies

Tags: iteration, assert, dafny

Hi  I have simplified the problem to a method that simply copies the elements of one array to another array. My problem is that the final assert  verifies yet the initial assert fails to verify even though I have a guard to ensure that initial assert only applies after the first time the loop is entered. Hence I think the final assert should imply the initial assert.

Any help much appreciated.

```
method simpImp(a:array<int>) returns (r:array<int>)
   {
    print "a ",a[..],"\n";
    r := new int[a.Length];  
    var i:nat := 0;
    while (i< a.Length) 
      decreases a.Length - i
      invariant a.Length  >= i
    {
        if (i> 0) { print  "  bool  ",r[i-1] == a[i-1],"\n";}
        else {print "*i ",i,"\n";}
        //if (i> 0) { assert   r[i-1] == a[i-1]; } //Fail
        //assert  (i>0) ==> r[i-1] == a[i-1];      //Fail
         r[i] := a[i];  
         i:= i +1;
        assert    r[i-1] == a[i-1]; 
    }
  }
method Main() {
var a:array<int> := new int[5];
a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4] := 10,2,30,4,3;
var iny:= simpImp(a);
print "r ",iny[..],"\n";
}
```

Comment: Instead of the two lines in `Main` that allocate and initialize array `a`, you can write `var a := new int[5] [10, 2, 30, 4, 3];`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to add something to your loop invariant to "remember" any facts you need to carry between iterations. Dafny analyzes the loop body in isolation, assuming only the loop invariants at the beginning of the body. So unless you add the fact to the loop invariant, it will be "forgotten" by Dafny.

In your simplified example, adding

```
    invariant i > 0 ==> r[i-1] == a[i-1]
```

to the loop causes the program to verify.

---

You can read more about loop invariants in the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49505325/438267). Note that that discussion is phrased in terms of establishing that loop invariants are preserved, but the reasoning is mostly identical to trying to establish that an assertion inside the loop body is valid. Please feel free to ask further questions!

Comment: Thanks James. I have to admit I am struggling to understand the syntactic requirements needed to  keep  Dafny's automatic theorem prover happy.

Comment: In fact, the need for the stronger loop invariant is actually implied by Hoare logic.